# Abort execution of Proguard if a note or waning has been given

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Is it possible to let Proguard stop execution after raising a note or warning?

Sometimes Proguard tells me to fix some errors, but most of the time the building of the APK file just continues and I have to manually check if any notes or warnings have been given which might need to get fixed.

For instance the following note will be displayed but the APK file will continue to be build after Proguard is finished (real package name is replaced with ***):

`Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'nl.***.InputLayout { void setSelectedItemContainer(nl.***.ItemContainerObject); }', but not the descriptor class 'nl.***.ItemContainerObject'`

Answer (score 1):

By default, ProGuard will fail the build if any warnings are output during the build, unless you have the rule -ignorewarnings (or -dontwarn) specified in your configuration.

Notes are usually not critical and do not lead to a build failure.

Comment: So it's not possible to halt execution once a note has been raised?